# Rails Collection of random records

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, random

My Database Table Structure is like as follows

```
Id  | Name  | Status  | Weight
------------------------------
1   | A     | 1       | 130
2   | A     | 2       | 140
3   | A     | 1       | 130
4   | A     | 1       | 120
5   | A     | 3       | 110
6   | A     | 1       | 100
7   | A     | 2       | 110
8   | A     | 2       | 100
9   | A     | 1       | 140
10  | A     | 2       | 130
11  | A     | 3       | 100
12  | A     | 3       | 110
13  | A     | 1       | 120
```

I would like to write a condition in my Rails model which would get all possible collection of records whose sum of `weight` is less than 260 and `status` 1

for eg Total Sum should be less than 260 and status is 1.. the results can be

records with id [1,4] where weight is 130 + 120 or [1,6] where weight is 130 + 100 etc... I want a random record with this condition

I can access a random record like

```
Model.offset(rand(Model.count)).first
```

But I want to access get the random records that accepts this condition..and can be a single record or multiple records

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.where(status: 1).group(:name).having('count(weight) < 260')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.where(status: 1).combination(2).to_a.select{|e| e.sum(&:weight) < 260 }.sample
```

You can change the value of combination argument for different combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my_records =  Model.where(status: 1).each_cons(2).select{|x,y| x.weight + y.weight < 260}
```

Now for random single:

```
my_records.sample # return single random record
```